# Failed: no intent for collection in archive

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Since i dropped my MongoDB database i get this error

[image: [Screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqIrg.png)

```
Failed: no intent for collection in archive:
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a limitation of mongodump and mongorestore that they won't work if there is a forward-slash in the collection name, because it is a path separator character at the OS level: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1163