# Mongodb: mongodump collections that their names contain a path separator '/'

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have a database with a lot of collections that have '/' in their names.
The problem is `mongodump` will fail in this circumstance.

> Failed: "CollectionNameWith/Sign" contains a path separator '/' and
> can't be dumped to the filesystem

And if I use `mongodump` with `--archive` flag, `mongodump` cannot export any document or `mongorestore` cannot work properly. ([same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796469/failed-no-intent-for-collection-in-archive))

I found the same problem in [mongodb jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1163), there isn't any solution for this problem.

Any comments would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** See how I solved the issue in my comment!

Comment: Finally, I migrate my db and remove '/' from collections name to solve this problem!